# Make character face direction

Tags: actionscript-3

I have one character which can face several directions: `t, b, l, r, tl, tr, bl, br`

The type of camera is top-down 2d

T stands for Top, which is when he is looking to the top of the screen
B = Bottom
L = Left
R = Right

The character can look to other directions, like the Top-Left of the screen, which is `tl`

How do I calculate which direction he should look to if I only have one variable, `rotation`?

Comment: What does rotation represent? Degrees in a circle?

Comment: Yes, from the center of the character, 0 degrees means he is looking to the right

Comment: is the rotation of your character following your mouse?

Comment: Yes and no, some characters are controlled by another class, which sets the rotation just like when it's controlled by a player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your rotation property is from -180 to 180 (this is the way DisplayObject.rotation behaves)

```
// this gives us an index of 0-7 for rotation. 
var direction:int = (character.rotation + 180) / 45;

// should you need a string representation, use an array like this:
var direction_labels:Array = ['b', 'bl', 'l', 'tl', 't', 'tr', 'r', 'br'];
trace(direction_labels[direction]);
```

Comment: you may need to change the order of the directions in the array depending on how you're interpreting the rotation, but it should be close enough.

Comment: This code doesn't work, the character would rotate 1 direction every 1 degree and the rotation is a Number, it would need to be rounded

Comment: It works, thanks. Here's the final code after I modified some things: `var dir:String = ['b', 'bl', 'l', 'tl', 't', 'tr', 'r', 'br'][int((rotation + 292.5) / 45) % 8]`